# How applications can be protected from errors in DLL module

Tags: c++, dll

I have DLL and application that will call some function in this dll. For example...

DLL function:

```
char const* func1() 
{ 
    return reinterpret_cast<char const*>(0x11223344); 
}
```

Application code:

```
func1 = reinterpret_cast<Func1Callback>(::GetProcAddress(hDll, "func1"));
blablabla
char const* ptr = func1();
cout << ptr;
```

That DLL is not under my control (plugin).. 
Same code will cause access violation in my application, so... Is there any mechanism that will allow to determine such errors?

Comment: If a DLL isn't "trusted" then consider an extension mechanism which is less powerful than running arbitrary code.  For instance: if you were writing a media player and wanted to provide for "skinning" you could pass the window handle to an arbitrary function in a DLL (which could format the hard drive...) or you could read a text file which had a list of visual PNG components.  The latter can be constrained more easily to not be malicious or buggy in a way that could cause a crash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the DLL can do anything your program could do the only reliable way is to load it into a separate worker lightweight process and once anything bad happens just restart the process. You'll need some protocol to pass data into the worker process and receive results.

Answer (score 1):

The dll is loaded into your process address space. If it accesses some invalid memory location your process will crash. I don't see any way around it other than not using this dll at all.

Comment: i search a way which allow for example print some message when dll returns illegal pointer or doing another strange things...

Answer (score 0):

If a DLL is returning junk memory addresses to your application, I'd say you shouldn't be using it, because it isn't performing its intended/desired function.

Also, don't try to guard against it by using the Win32 IsBad*Ptr class of functions, as the MSDN documentation states (see also [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx) by Raymond Chen for a good description of why not).

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose function call into try catch block, it'll help not to crush entire application right at function call, but nobody can garantee, that dll loaded will not alter memory somwhere in your code, in this case yo'll get hard to debug crash in other place. So you can probably raise some protection for just access violation, but anyway cannot fully protext you application for some side effects.